How to use subquery statements in Entity::find of SeaORM?
I want to use Rust's SeaORM to implement the following SQL code: SELECT grade, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT student) FROM (SELECT id, grade, student FROM math_class ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000) AS math_class_grade GROUP BY grade.The code is as follows:
#[derive(Debug, FromQueryResult)]
struct MathGrade {
    garde: String,
    students: Vec<String>,
}


let subquery = Query::select()
        .columns([
            math::Column::Id,
            math::Column::Grade,
            math::Column::Student,
        ])
        .from(math::Entity)
        .order_by(math::Column::Id, Order::Desc)
        .limit(10_000)
        .to_string(sea_orm::sea_query::backend::PostgresQueryBuilder);

    let results = math::Entity::find()
        .select_only()
        .column(math::Column::Grade)
        .expr_as(
            Expr::cust(&format!(
                "ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT student) FROM ({subquery}) AS math_class_grade"
            )),
            "students",
        )
        .group_by(math::Column::Grade)
        .into_model::<MathGrade>()
        .all(db)
        .await?;
    println!("{:?}", results);

However, this code fails to produce the expected result. My PostgreSQL table structure is as follows:



id
grade
student




1
A
tom


2
A
jerry


3
B
woody


4
B
buzz


5
C
jessie


6
C
rex



The expected result is to obtain a structure like this:{ MathGrade {grade: A, students: [tom, jerry]}, MathGrade {grade: B, students: [woody, buzz]}, MathGrade {grade: C, students: [jessie, rex]} }. However, after running the program, there is no output. The configuration of Cargo.toml is as follows, and the Rust compiler version I am using is rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15).  I would appreciate it if someone could help me clear up this confusion, and any reply are welcome. Thanks.
[package]
name = "pgsql_query_demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[workspace]
members = [".", "entity"]

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "^1.32", features = ["full"] }
sea-orm = { version = "^1.1", features = [ "sqlx-postgres", "runtime-tokio-rustls", "macros" ] }
entity ={ path = "entity" }


Try converting the query to String with postgres db backend

Thank you for your response,But my subquery is generated as a string using the postgresql db backend. I don't understand why there is no output.

No I meant to convert the entire query, the find one, to string and check it to see if your required query and the generated query match

Thank you for your reply. Do you mean directly using:let sql = r#"SELECT grade, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT student) FROM (SELECT id, grade, student FROM math_class ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000) AS math_class_grade GROUP BY grade"#;and then executing:let results = db.query_all(Statement::from_string(sea_orm::DbBackend::Postgres, sql)).await?; as the approach?
